# How to change code and add screen resolution to function?

Tags: jquery

I got this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>280) $('.scrollup').fadeIn(); 
    else $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
});
```

and I dont know how to add condition like screen resolution and get something like that:

```
if($(this).scrollTop()>280) // and screen resolution for device is more than 500 px
```

Thanks for the help :) (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Add an AND to your if condition:

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 280 && $(window).width() > 500){
     //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Hahahah - it worked, i make similar code but i made 1 mistake. Thx :) Ryan :)